# Basic hot reloading with webpack 5 not working properly

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader, react-refresh

[image]

### Issues

- It is loading the entire page

---

- **Operating System:** *macOS Big Sur 11.2*
- **Node Version:** *v14.15.4*
- **NPM Version:** *6.14.10*
- **webpack Version:** *^5.19.0*
- **webpack-dev-server Version:** *^4.0.0-beta.0*
- **Browser:** *Google Chrome Version 88*
- [x] This is a **bug**

#### Code

Repository link: https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpack5Hot

- [`master`](https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpack5Hot) branch it's using only basic webpack-dev-server configuration without any plugins
- [`react-hot-loader`](https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpack5Hot/tree/react-hot-loader) branch it's using [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) plugin. **[Pull Request #1](https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpack5Hot/pull/1)**
- [`react-refresh-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpack5Hot/tree/react-refresh-webpack-plugin) branch it's using [pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin) webpack plugin. **[Pull Request #2](https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpack5Hot/pull/2)**

#### Expected Behavior

In all case... should not reload the page and only reload the portion that's changed

#### Actual Behavior

It's Always reloading the entire page.

#### How can we reproduce the behavior?

Just clone the repository [ridermansb/webpack5Hot](https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpack5Hot)

- `npm install`
- `npm start`

And try update `Header` component

Comment: Hi @ridermansb did you solve it, I am encountering the same issue with webpack 5 and webpack-dev-server 4.0 beta too :(

Comment: @NuongNguyen I just downgrade the webpack to v4